# Change 2 frames with 1 click

Tags: javascript, html

Hey i want to change 2 frames with just one click

```
window.parent.framename.href('qwerty');
window.parent.framename2.href('qwerty2');
```

HELP ME

Comment: What is wrong with your code and what is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`href` is a *property*, not a function. And it's a property of link (`a`) elements, not frames.

The location of a frame is defined by its `src` attribute, which is reflected as the `src` property ([`HTMLFrameElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-97790553), [`HTMLIFrameElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#htmliframeelement)), so **if** `framename` and `framename2` really refer to frames, and provided the code isn't in the window referenced by `framename` (in which case I'm not quite sure the second line will run, although I expect it probably would), then:

```
window.parent.framename.src = 'qwerty';
window.parent.framename2.src = 'qwerty2';
```